# iOS app crashes on iphone device when using httpclient and .net maui

Tags: ios, .net, crash, httpclient, maui

Build environment:
Macbook M1
vscode(1.69.0) as well as vs2022 (17.3)

Steps to reproduce:

- create new Maui app
- add nuget package "Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="6.0.0" to project
- Modify MauiProgram.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<EndPointAHttpClient>(client =>
        {
            var EndPointA = "https://www.montemagno.com/";
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(EndPointA);
        });
public class EndPointAHttpClient
{
    public EndPointAHttpClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        Client = client;
    }

    public HttpClient Client { get; }
}
```

- Publish:
  dotnet publish <project.csproj> -f:net6.0-ios -c:Release /p:ServerAddress=<xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx> /p:ServerUser=user /p:TcpPort=58181  /p:ServerPassword=pwd -p:AotAssemblies=false
- Install on iphone using Transporter/TestFlight

**CRASHES WHEN OPENING THE APP**

***Please let me know:***

***1. Is there any demo code that works***

***2. Kindly provide advise on how I can use HttpClient in a .net Maui app***

Comment: I am not familiar with Maui but I found a demo about using HttpClient in Maui. Here is the website. https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/main/6.0/WebServices/TodoREST/TodoREST/Services/HttpsClientHandlerService.cs

Answer (score 1):

Use the code found here. https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/6.0/WebServices/TodoREST/TodoREST/Services

Grab the RestService, IRestService, HttpsClientHandlerService and IHttpsClientHandlerService.

Get the Contstants file as well.

https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/main/6.0/WebServices/TodoREST/TodoREST/Constants.cs

Makes sure you add your Url to the HttpsClientHandlerService like so. I was getting a System.Net.WebException: Error: TrustFailure. The only way I was able to catch what was happening was using Sentry.io. I guessed that this might be the problem.

```
public bool IsSafeUrl(NSUrlSessionHandler sender, string url, Security.SecTrust trust)
        {           
            if (url.StartsWith("https://localhost") || url.StartsWith("https://yourservice.azurewebsites.net"))
                return true;
            return false;
        }
```

Then change this line.

```
var handler = new NSUrlSessionHandler
            {
                TrustOverrideForUrl = IsSafeUrl
            };
```

Comment: This fixed it for me:  <PropertyGroup>
    <UseInterpreter Condition="$(TargetFramework.EndsWith('-ios'))">true</UseInterpreter>
</PropertyGroup>